# Span of parabolic inductions of discrete series representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be the $\mathbf{Q}_p$-points in a $p$-adic reductive group, and let $R(G)$ be the Grothendieck group of the category $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ of finite-length admissible smooth complex representations of $G$. Let $S \subset \mathrm{Rep}(G)$ be the set of objects of the form $\mathrm{ind}_{P}^{G} \sigma$, where $P=MU$ is a standard parabolic and $\sigma$ is an irreducible (essentially) discrete series representation of $M$. Here $P=G$ is allowed. Consider the following three properties of $G$, in decreasing order of strength.

P1. $S$ gives a $\mathbf{Z}$-basis of $R(G)$.

P2. The elements of $S$ span $R(G)$.

P3. The elements of $S$ span $R(G) \otimes \mathbf{Q}$.

If $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(D)$ for some finite extension $F/\mathbf{Q}_p$ and some $F$-division algebra $D$ (or if $G$ is a product of groups of this form), then P1 holds by work of Zelevinsky and Tadic (see Lemma 2.9 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eswshin/RZspacesELtype.pdf) for the references). Expert "TK" told me that P2 probably fails for general $G$, but didn't suggest a concrete counterexample. Is there any chance that P3 is always true? If not, is there a standard example of a group $G$ for which P3 (or P2) clearly fails?